# What is the difference between [maritime] and [law-of-the-sea]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

I am wondering what the difference between tag [maritime](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/maritime) and tag [law-of-the-sea](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/law-of-the-sea) is. Does the former encompass maritime law in general, whereas the latter pertains specifically to the [United Nations Convention on the Law of the Sea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_Nations_Convention_on_the_Law_of_the_Sea) (UNCLOS)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've suggested they should be synonyms - please vote for it.

Comment: Agree. They should be synonyms.

Comment: Just completed!